# Material.io color design system

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, vs-web-site-project, figma

Hope everyone is doing well.

Just had a quick  question about the color design system from Material.io
I'm trying to create a color design system in Figma and I was wondering if anyone can tell me what the numbers under each color swatch means. There's a color square and under it, it has 50 or 100 or 700. Does anyone know what these numbers mean.

Much Appreciated

Comment: may be this question and answers can help clarify https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/43021

Answer (score 0):

They are just arbitrary numbers to help create a scale of color values. e.g. "grey-50" and "grey-100" indicate there are two grey colors in my color system. Then in my CSS by referencing grey-50 i get one color grey and referencing grey-100 i get the other.